# Grails: Spring Security Plugin URL Matching

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have one simple requirement and I am not able to find the URL pattern which will suit it. I have the spring security plugin all configured and working fine. A new requirement came up where:

My application context is: http:///ramaApp. Now here is how the roles should work:

http:///ramaApp, http:///ramaApp/controller1, http:///ramaApp/controller2 etc should be accessible to ROLE-A, ROLE-B, ROLE-C

http:///ramaApp can be accessed by ROLE-Z too. But he shouldn't be able to access the rest of the URL patterns. That means, he can only access the application context but not any further controller URLs.

URL: appName/* should work for certain roles ( eg ROLE-A, ROLE-B and ROLE-C )

URL: appName/a*, appName/b*, appName/c* ... appName/z* i.e any controller shouldn't be accessible for some roles ( eg ROLE-Z ).

I am configuring the URL mapping to roles in the database table RequestMap. How do I configure the above requirement in the RequestMap table i.e the config_attribute and url columns?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the question "How do I configure Spring Security RequestMap for ROLE-Z to not be allowed to access ANY URL?" Sorry, your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I have edited the question and tried to be more clear this time. Any help?